# RStudio - dark theme - white menu bar

Tags: rstudio, archlinux, cinnamon

I have fresh install of Arch Linux with Cinnamon desktop.
When I change theme to dark in RStudio top panel is still white.
Why is so and how can I change it?

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Have you updated to the most recent version of RStudio?