# Not change color menubar RStudio

Tags: qt, debian, qt5, rstudio, arch

[image]

I can't change color menubar

I try:
qt5ct set dark theme

```
/etc/environment
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct

cd /usr/lib/rstudio/bin/plugins/platformthemes
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platformthemes/libappmenu-qt5.so libappmenu-qt5.so
```

This problem is on debian and arch 
the same problem [arch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57227592/rstudio-dark-theme-white-menu-bar)